# My background is under navbar.How to set the background just below the navbar?

Tags: java, android

My background hides under the navbar.
How can I put the background start showing just below the navbar?

[image]

code:

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/backgroundnew"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Comment: Maybe it’s not under the nav bar; maybe it’s being cropped?  What happens if you use the `centerInside` scaling mode?

Comment: its works but the background shows with white bars at the sides now :D i need fullscreen

Comment: I’m sure android gives you a way to set a solid color background behind your content, but I’ve never done any android development, so I’m afraid I can’t help you there.

Comment: Set a margin top to `?attr/actionBarSize`.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/HBL0i gap

Comment: @Miche I believe it's not being cut, but as you have provided `centerCrop`, it's getting cropped. put `fitXY` instead of `centerCrop` & see. You'll see stretched full image.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity_main.xml, Have you closed the toolbar correctly?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you didn't close your toolbar, the view is overlapped.